# SQL Server 2005 to 2012 Replication, cannot access replicated data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2005, replication

I have created publication (snapshot, small table with 10 rows) on MS SQL Server 2005. Then, I created push subscription on MS SQL Server 2012. When I try to select data form table, process takes several minutes after that I got error. It looks like table is locked.

### My Observations

- Replication monitor shows everything is OK.
- Distribution service is running on MS SQL Server 2005.
- I see replication files created on network share.

Why can I not access the table ?

Comment: Please add exact error to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in [Frequently Asked Questions for Replication Administrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151740.aspx):

> Are tables locked during snapshot generation?
>
> The length of time that the locks are taken depends on the type of
>   replication used:
>
> ```
> For merge publications, the Snapshot Agent does not take any locks.
>
> For transactional publications, by default the Snapshot Agent takes locks only during the initial phase of snapshot generation.
>
> For snapshot publications the Snapshot Agent takes locks during the entire snapshot generation process.
> ```
>
> Because locks prevent other users from updating the tables, the
>   Snapshot Agent should be scheduled to execute during periods of lower
>   activity on the database, especially for snapshot publications.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by increasing server working memory.